# Passing parameters when setting the Refresh HTTP header with setHeader() method in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-headers, page-refresh

I am using `setHeader()` method to refresh a JSP page as shown below

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "5; URL=passDebitCard.jsp");
```

Now I want to send parameters to this *passDebitCard.jsp* after refreshing for 5 seconds
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `response.setHeader("Refresh", "5; URL=passDebitCard.jsp?param1=test1&param2=test2");` ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie +1. Just wanted to offer the same solution. It works without any problem. the only thing to watch for is the OP is giving the **relative** URL. It works too, but he must be sure the desired page is relative to the resource it sends it initially.

Comment: @informatik01 right for the relative path, I'll provide a full answer including that!

Answer (score 1):

You can append `GET` parameters to the URL like this :

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "5; URL=passDebitCard.jsp?param1=test1&param2=test2");
```

You should also put an absolute path to this URL as a good practice, like this :

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "5; URL=" + request.contextPath + "/passDebitCard.jsp?param1=test1&param2=test2");
```

so you won't have path problem even if the previous page is moved or different.

Comment: test1 and test2 are user-created strings but i want to pass parameters to this passDebitCard.jsp which are parameters from the last form

Comment: @user1982491 you can replace test1 by `" + variableName + "` and same for test2, is that what you are expecting?