# How to transfer parameter to redirect web

Tags: java, html

We know that we can redirect an website by putting this below the  tag:

```
<head>
  <meta content=0;url=http://www.google.com http-equiv='Refresh'/>
</head>
```

But what happen if the link I want to redirect is not `google.com` but it is stored in a string variable that I processed from my Java code? I know if it load from head down, then it will redirect immediately to that page without going through the following code right? So, how to combine the string that I extracted and let the website to load to that link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782263/passing-parameters-when-setting-the-refresh-http-header-with-setheader-method/16782599#16782599

Comment: I saw the post but it is not duplicated, I tried and it not work. I know that I almost there. I can use this to redirect my site: '<% response.sendRedirect("name"); %>' but in case redirectURL is a string variable called "name". If I use this: '<h1>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>' in the html, I can display that value of variable "name", so now how should I modify to put that value appear in the '<% response.sendRedirect("name"); %>'?

Answer (score 0):

From JSP (or servlet):

```
<%
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

Where redirectURL is the variable containing the page you want to go to.

Comment: I m new to JSP, so how tat jsp script can work with my java code ? As I search, that jsp can put to html file, just change the .html to .jsp. But I am quite sure, I cannot past the current java code to that html file right ?

Comment: Ok, now I know that I almost there. I can use this to redirect my site: '<% response.sendRedirect("redirectURL"); %>' but in case redirectURL is a variable (string). How should I modify here ?

Comment: Ok, now I know that I almost there. I can use this to redirect my site: '<% response.sendRedirect("name"); %>' but in case redirectURL is a string variable called "name". If I use this: '<h1>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>' in the html, I can display that value of variable "name", so now how should I modify to put that value appear in the '<% response.sendRedirect("name"); %>'?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I figured it out:
First, need to construct the index.jsp and its java class in an web app:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html
then in the index.jsp, use this to get variable from that java class and redirect:

```
<%@page import = "org.mypackage.Webredirect.*" %>
<%Webredirect obj = new Webredirect();%>
 <%response.sendRedirect( obj.getName());%>
```

thank you.